# Tweetdeck replacement for Mac

Tags: facebook, twitter

Is there a Tweetdeck replacement for mac? A program that'll allow me to post to both my Twitter account and Facebook accounts with a single action?

Comment: Tweetdeck run on Mac, no? Isn't it an Adobe Air app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably check out [Socialite](http://www.apparentsoft.com/socialite) ($20).

Comment: only trouble is, you cannot post into two social networks with one action. You have to "select twitter", post, then select facebook, and re-post. Unless I'm missing this feature.

Comment: Ah, you're probably right; I haven't used it myself, but knew that it handled multiple networks.

Answer (score 3):

Try [HootSuite](http://hootsuite.com/). If you want it to become a desktop app, use [this](http://help.hootsuite.com/entries/241907-what-is-hootsuite-desktop-fluid).

Otherwise, you can use the official Twitter client and configure the Twitter Facebook App to post your twitter updates on facebook.

You can also use [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/) and [Mozilla's Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/) (as a extension in the browser or as a standalone) to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The latest [Twitter API terms of service](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/api_terms)  specifically prohibit clients posting to multiple social networks with a single click

> 5E: You may not use Twitter Content or other data collected from end users of your Client to create or maintain a separate status update or social network database or service.

So, even if clients like Hootsuite allow it now, I would expect them to not be able to do that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[Babble](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/32780/babble/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.